# Open autocomplete on click

Tags: jquery, events, autocomplete

I'm using the Jquery autocomplete: [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

I would like to open the autocomplete with event click:

```
$(div).live('click', function(e){

...?????....

});
```

What can I do to open it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation of [search](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search) method:

> Can be called with an empty string and minLength: 0 to display all
>   items.

So, your code should be:

```
$(div).live('click', function(e) {
  $(div).autocomplete("option", "minLength", 0).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work..The autoc. is attach to an input and click div is a button so: `$("#button").live('click', function() {
  $("#input").autocomplete("option", "minLength", 0).autocomplete("search", "");
});`  Doesnt work...Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your input with autocomplete have `id="input"`?

Comment: It actually has id="searchbox" :) (Not that it should matter right..)

Comment: Then you should use `$("#searchbox")` instead of `$("#input")`.

Comment: Use searchbox...are you kidding me:) Anyway, your answer was right after all, I forgot to put something to search for, like a var: `autocomplete("search", "SomeVar");` Thank you.